# Evaluating KendoUI Scheduler control and dhtmlxScheduler - Responsive

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Since couple of days, I am evaluating KendoUI Scheduler control and dhtmlxScheduler. My main focus is on "Responsive" design, seems like KendoUI takes upper hand and dhtmlxScheduler seems to be not supporting.

Need help in understanding if Responsive is completely independent of these controls? 
Please help in making decision which one I should go for?